# Is the use of rather in this sentence correct or is there some other problem?

Tags: word-usage

One of the bold words in the following sentence is used in a wrong way.
I believe it is something to do with "rather"

Why **would** you **rather** **stay** at home to go out **tonight**?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Are you certain that you bolded all of the potential problems?

Comment: None of the bold words looks wrong to me.  "To" is the word that looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

The word "rather" indicates a preference for something. In this case, someone would prefer to stay home instead of going out for the evening. The problem in the sentence is the word "to". The sentence should say "Why would you rather stay at home than go out tonight?"